# How to install compatible debug symbols for systemsettings?

Tags: apt, package-management

Since there's no `systemsettings-dbg` on Ubuntu 18.04, I found on [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) that I could add repositories which contain `systemsettings-dbgsym` and try to install that. I've added the repositories, did `apt update`. But when trying to install the package I get an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 systemsettings-dbgsym : Depends: systemsettings (= 4:5.12.7-0ubuntu0.1) but 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
```

I thought that I might have too old version of `systemsettings`, but apparently not:

```
$ sudo apt-get install systemsettings
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
systemsettings is already the newest version (4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1).
systemsettings set to manually installed.
```

Apparently `ddebs.ubuntu.com` and `archive.ubuntu.com` are not synchronized in package versions.

So, how can I install the debug symbols for the `systemsettings` package? Or how can I upgrade my package so that its version matched that of `-dbgsym` one?

Comment: 5.12.7 is in -proposed. 5.12.6 is in -updates. Does not seem like a sync problem. Check your sources.

Comment: @user535733 thanks, this points into the right direction. I've made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by [@user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733), I found what the problem is. I just had to remove (or comment out) the line with `-proposed` from the `ddebs.list` generated when following the Wiki.Ubuntu page on debug symbol packages.

After removing this line and doing `apt update`, I've successfully installed `systemsettings-dbgsym`.